Trying to delete/rename a copied folder ask for admin request and fails to use recycle bin
I've some issue with some of my projects. When I copy a folder in a project, and paste it in another folder in the same project, then try to delete it, it shows me a pop-up saying it requires the administrator rights to delete it. If you accept, it fails to use the recycle bin and instead, ask you if you want to delete it permanently.
Kind of same thing happens when I try to rename the copied folder, VSCode just run the "processing" animation indefinitely and sticks on it, I'm forced to restart it.
It sounds like it can't alter folders that are copied for some reasons. I checked the permissions from the folders properties and all is fine, the system as the full control as well as other folders which I have no problem with.
Does someone has any idea about what happens?
Thank you in advance.
OS: Windows 11 23H2 Build 22631.3880
VSCode:

Version: 1.91.1 (user setup)
Commit: f1e16e1e6214d7c44d078b1f0607b2388f29d729
Date: 2024-07-09T22:06:49.809Z
Electron: 29.4.0
ElectronBuildId: 9728852
Chromium: 122.0.6261.156
Node.js: 20.9.0
V8: 12.2.281.27-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22631

